# Get days, hours, minutes, and seconds left

Tags: php, node.js, twig, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 and trying to fetch how many time is left to start a event. I have future date.

when I do `{{content.field_event_start_date_time }}` it outputs:

```
Thu, 05/20/2021 - 12:00 which is my start date of the event
```

Now, I used following code to calcuate days difference that is not working:

```
{# endDate and startDate are strings or DateTime objects #}
{% set difference = date({{content.field_event_start_date_time  }}).diff(date(startDate)) %}
{% set leftDays = difference.days %}
{% if leftDays == 1 %}
  1 day
{% else %}
  {{ leftDays }} days
{% endif %}
```

any idea how can I get days, hours, minutes and seconds left?

Comment: You can use Carbon library of php. Or moment library of js.

Answer (score 0):

Do not include too much logic into the view layer. It makes the code less readable. Views should mostly receive variables calculated in Drupal's hook system.

I would recommend using [`hook_preprocess_HOOK()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/8.9.x), and calculate the date there.

For example, in your theme file:

```
function hook_preprocess_YOUR_VIEW_NAME(&$variables) {
  $variables['my_date'] = // ... calculate your date
}
```